# Can I unlock any/all of the divine items corresponding to relics in my Beyond recipe?

Tags: demoncrawl

Each relic has a corresponding divine item, and you can unlock each divine item by winning a Beyond run created using that relic. But I'm not sure that's the whole story. So far, I've unlocked 17 divine items by winning quite a few more Beyond runs, and I always use 3 different relics, assuming that if I get lucky I could unlock 2 or even 3 of those divine items in one run. But I've never unlocked more than 1 divine item in a run.

So, can you only unlock one divine item per run? Is only one of the relics in the recipe eligible to unlock a divine item? Or can you actually unlock all of the divine items corresponding to the relics used in one run, and I've just been getting unlucky?